# Deriving implementation of pure virtual function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class, pure-virtual, virtual-functions

Consider following example

```
#include <iostream>

struct PureVirtual {
    virtual void Function() = 0;
};

struct FunctionImpl {
    virtual void Function() {
        std::cout << "FunctionImpl::Function()" << std::endl;
    }   
};

struct NonPureVirtual : public FunctionImpl, public PureVirtual {
    using FunctionImpl::Function;
};

int main() {
    NonPureVirtual c;
    c.Function();
}
```

Compiler (GCC 4.9, Clang 3.5) exits with error

```
test.cpp:18:20: error: variable type 'NonPureVirtual' is an abstract class
    NonPureVirtual c;
                   ^
test.cpp:4:18: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'Function' in 'NonPureVirtual'
    virtual void Function() = 0;
                 ^
```

But when I don't derive form `PureVirtual` everything is OK. This is weird because Standard  *10.4.4* says

> A class is abstract if it contains or inherits at least one pure
> virtual function for which the final overrider is pure virtual.

They are not saying anything about what the *final overrider* is but I suppose it should be `FunctionImpl::Function()` especially when I made it available through `using` directive. So why is still `NonPureVirtual` abstract class and how can I fix this.

Comment: `PureVirtual` is not the base of `FunctionImpl`, so...

Comment: `public FunctionImpl, public PureVirtual` -> `Function` is visible through both classes and specifically from PureVirtual, no virtual inheritance, so it makes it an abstract class. A guess.

Comment: @Simple - I don't think so, or at least - bug in may versions of gcc. I have had the same case, I worked around it, but I don't have the answer here.

Comment: @Constructor - exactly, that's the case.. The problem is why `NonPureVirtual` is abstract.

Comment: @DumbCoder - I don't think so, you need `virtual` inheritance only when you have the "diamond inheritance" - this is different case.

Comment: Nevermind, it's not a bug. I completely misread the question. Obviously `NonPureVirtual` is not an ABC when you don't have a pure virtual function.

Comment: The reason it doesn't compile when you inherit from `PureVirtual` is that you're only affecting the scope/accessibility of `FunctionImpl::Function` with `using`; you're not overriding anything.

Comment: You can do `/* virtual */ void Function() { FunctionImpl::Function(); }` in `NonPureVirtual` **but I have no idea if this is well defined**. Most probably - not.

Comment: @Kiril Kirov That's the case, and it's the source of the problem.

Comment: @Constructor - the idea is how to make it work, **without** making `PureVirtual` base of `FunctionImpl` ..

Comment: @KirilKirov I replied to your previous message, sorry. A good idea is in Matthieu M. answer.

Comment: There's a great post on Sutter's Mill/GOTW pertaining to using the `override` keyword in [Overriding Virtual Functions](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/22/gotw-5-solution-overriding-virtual-functions/). It also highlights some unexpected pitfalls related to differing default parameters in base and derived classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`FunctionImpl::Function` and `PureVirtual::Function` are different functions from different classes.

Their respective types are `void (FunctionImpl::*)()` and `void (PureVirtual::*)()`.
Since `PureVirtual` and `FunctionImpl` are unrelated classes, these function types are unrelated.

They happen to have the same name and the same parameters and return type, but since they're different, the `using FunctionImpl::Function` line doesn't make that function an override of the one in `PureVirtual`.

And if you declared a variable of type `void (PureVirtual::*)()`, you wouldn't be able to assign `FunctionImpl::Function` to it.

In other words, the final override of `PureVirtual::Function` is the original one in `PureVirtual`, which is pure virtual.

For making what you want possible, Matthieu M.'s answer (using a forwarding call) is the way to go, it seems.

Comment: Yes, this explains the case, my exaplanation was the same, but "how to fix it?". You can see my comment above: "You can do `/* virtual */ void Function() { FunctionImpl::Function(); }` in `NonPureVirtual` **but I have no idea if this is well defined. Most probably - not**."

Comment: What I tried, for example, was `void PureVirtual::Function() { FunctionImpl::Function(); } ` but this is not a valid syntax, as expected.

Comment: @KirilKirov I suspect it could be unfixable, but I'm not sure. Renaming is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Yes, this is how I "worked around" this issue, when I had it. But I still have hope, there's a better way :)

Comment: @Kiril What about `struct NonPureVirtual : ... { void Function() { } };
... c.FunctionImpl::Function();`

Comment: @remyabel - no sure how different this is. Yes, `FunctionImpl::Function` will be called, but..

Comment: So how do we distinguish two functions. I've always thought signature is what distinguishes two functions in C++. Those functions obviously have the same signature.

Comment: @tomas789 I added some more about the function types.

Comment: @tomas789 There's more to a signature of a (member) function than just the name and parameter types. It also includes the cv-qualifiers, ref-qualifier and **the class the function is member of**. The fact that some other class, which `PureVirtual` and `FunctionImpl` know nothing about, derives from both of them is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a `using` directive and have to resort to a fowarding call instead:

```
struct NonPureVirtual : public FunctionImpl, public PureVirtual {
    virtual void Function() override {
        return FunctionImpl::Function();
    }
};
```

And yes, [it works as expected](http://ideone.com/rjqTLC).

Comment: I don't think `override` changes anything, it's still not clear which base function it does override, or I'm wrong? And I wouldn't rely on a test for such cases.

Comment: And I don't understand your comment under @suspectus 's deleted answer. I mean - how does your answer solves the ambiguity issue in suspectus?

Comment: @KirilKirov: `override` changes nothing, it simply is good form in C++11 to tag as `override` functions that are in fact overrides; with or without `override`, `NonPureVirtual::Function` just overrides **both** `FunctionImpl::Function` and `PureVirtual::Function`. Regarding the ambiguity: there is **no ambiguity** in @suspectus's answer, however it used copy/paste to reproduce behavior which is to be avoided for maintenance's sake.

Comment: +1, I had no idea you could override two functions "simultaneously".

Answer (score 2):

You're attributing a using declaration with something that it doesn't do. What it does is (From draft n3337, 7.3.3/1):

> ... using-declaration introduces a name into the declarative region in which the *using-declaration* appears.

Later from the same paragraph:

> If a *using-declaration* names a constructor (3.4.3.1), it implicitly declares a set of constructors in the
>   class in which the *using-declaration* appears (12.9); **otherwise the name speciﬁed in a using-declaration is a
>   synonym for the name of some entity declared elsewhere.**

In your case, `FunctionImpl::Function` is first declared in `FunctionImpl` class and it is its member. A using-declaration doesn't change that fact, as paragraph 16 says further down:

> For the purpose of overload resolution, the functions which are introduced by a *using-declaration* into a derived class will be treated as though they were members of the derived class. In particular, the implicit `this` parameter shall be treated as if it were a pointer to the derived class rather than to the base class. **This has no effect on the type of the function, and in all other respects the function remains a member of
>   the base class.**

Now on to the definition of overriding (10.3/2):

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualiﬁcation, and ref-qualiﬁer (or absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it *overrides* `Base::vf`. For convenience we say that any virtual function overrides itself.

And there's also the definition of a final overrider in the same paragraph.

> A virtual member function `C::vf` of a class object `S` is a *ﬁnal overrider* unless the most derived class (1.8) of which `S` is a base class subobject (if any) declares or inherits another member function that overrides `vf`. In a derived class, if a virtual member function of a base class subobject has more than one ﬁnal overrider the program is ill-formed. [...]

I think that makes it clear that you can't use a using declaration to override a virtual function. A possible fix is in [Matthieu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20549400/947836).